# How to print a string formatted properly

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit

I am doing Test Driven Development.So I created a case that needs to send an array of strings to the function.That function will check if the array has any uppercase letter strings.If there is then it needs to print all the strings as "name , name, name and name are amazing".So before the last one it should be putting an "and".

It is sometimes giving me dead code error because there are other cases that might be interfering with the execution of this case.

Test Case

```
@Test
    void testAcceptsAJumbleOfUpperCaseAndLowerCase() {
            theAmazingPeter obj = new theAmazingPeter();             
            String[] arr = {"Peter","GUNEET"};
            String result = obj.AmazingPerson(arr);
            assertEquals("Peter, and GUNEET are amazing",result);
        }
    }
```

Statement

```
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (names.length >= 1 && names[i].equals(names[i].toUpperCase())) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
                if (i == names.length - 1) {
                    sb.append("and ");
                }
            }
            sb.append(names[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString() + " are amazing");
    }
    String result = sb.toString() + " are amazing";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you try implementing toString() in theAmazingPeter ?

Comment: @Vebbie yes the final output i am returning is using that toString() method

Comment: If you can share your output format here, Vs what do you actually want instead?

Comment: @Vebbie So if the input is like this [“JIGESHA”, “Peter”, “Marcos”, “Albert”] then the output should be Peter, Marcos, and Albert are amazing. JIGESHA ALSO!

Answer (score 1):

If it is needed to check if the string contains capital letter, it will need to be implemented as following:

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    char ch;

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(names[i].charAt(0))) {
            if (i == names.length - 1) {
                sb.append(" and " + names[i]);
            } else if (i == names.length - 2) {
                sb.append(names[i]);
            } else {
                sb.append(names[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString() + " are amazing");
    String result = sb.toString() + " are amazing";
    return result;
```

Comment: I think we can get away with not having a nested `for` loop to check for the caps as we just need to check the first letter and `break` out afterwards. This would reduce the time complexity.

Comment: @DarshanMehta : Right. Please post the implementation as your answer which can help people to solve it differently. Thanks.

Comment: As my suggestion didn't provide a different prospective, I have edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code is wrong:

```
if(names.length >= 1 && names[i].equals(names[i].toUpperCase()))
```

This if statement comes true only when all the letters of string are capital letters.

For example: if `names[i]` contains `"Peter"` then `names[i].toUpperCase()` equals `"PETER"` and the expression will return `false`. But what you want is accepting this string because it contains capital letter.

Instead doing this, you can use `Character.isUpperCase(char)` method.

```
public boolean containsUpper(String s){
      for (int i = 0 ; i< s.length(); i++){
          if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
             return true; 
      }
      return false;
}
```

You may call this function for every string then continue.